# between query for dates not working as i want

Tags: sql-server

i am working on SQL query which take records between two dates "from" To "to" as show in below picture.my query working well but when i change "to" date from 24 to 23 then it does not display the record of 23 date,means last row not display.

[image]
my SQL query is given below:

```
select  *  from  prescription_master where  (pr.date between @from_date and @to_date) or (pr.date=@to_date)
```

i want that the record of 23 date also display when i select 23 date from "to" date picker.for this purpose i use "or (pr.date=@to_date)" in above query but it not working.how i can solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to handle time part:

```
select  *  
from  prescription_master 
where  (CAST(pr.date AS DATE) between @from_date and @to_date) 
   or  (CAST(pr.date AS DATE) = @to_date)
   -- this also will made a query non-SARGable
```

When you provide parameter the date is set to `23-06-2019 00:00:00` and you are comparing it with `23-06-2019 13:08:00`

Comment: thank you i try it and its working well ...if we take just date type in database table then also casting is required.?

Comment: @Ubaid If you alter data type from DATETIME to DATE then you lose hour/minute/sec part, but then the cast is not needed. The point is that you should confirm if there is a businees requirement to store it with such granularity.